# ClassCastException even after type casting

Tags: classcastexception

I got a problem with iterating List which got prepared from HQL.
I am querying DB on a single table mapped to very simple class.

After iterating the same list and type casting to same class during iteration I am getting ClassCastException.

Code :

```
import HectorRequest;
import EDIMigrateData;

SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Query qry = session.createQuery("select hr from HectorRequest hr");

List result = qry.list();
for (Iterator it = result.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
   Object o = it.next();
   if(o instanceof HectorRequest){
      HectorRequest h = (HectorRequest) o;
      System.out.println("ID: " + h.getId());
   }
}
```

I wonder here If I am typecasting to the same class it is giving ClassCastException.

```
if(o instanceof HectorRequest) {
  HectorRequest h = (HectorRequest) o;
  System.out.println("ID: " + h.getId());
}
```

The control is not coming into the above if statement.
If I remove the above IF condition it is throwing

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: HectorRequest
```

Below is my hibernate mapping xml for `HectorRequest` class.

Below is my Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN""http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"><hibernate-configuration><session-factory><property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property><property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@//apludc01clu20-scan-oravip.dci.bt.com:61901/C2BM2_ANY</property><property name="hibernate.connection.username">s3</property><property name="hibernate.connection.password">**</property><property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property><property name="hibernate.default_schema">s3</property><property name="show_sql">true</property><property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property><mapping resource="resources/config/hector_request.hbm.xml"></mapping></session-factory></hibernate-configuration>
```

Below is the output:

```
Hibernate: select hectorrequ0_.ID as ID0_, hectorrequ0_.ROUTER_TEL as ROUTER2_0_, hectorrequ0_.FLAGVALUE as FLAGVALUE0_, hectorrequ0_.FLAGPOS as FLAGPOS0_, hectorrequ0_.ACCOUNTNO as ACCOUNTNO0_, hectorrequ0_.CUSTOMERIDENTITY as CUSTOMER6_0_, hectorrequ0_.CRMSOURCE as CRMSOURCE0_, hectorrequ0_.DATASOURCE as DATASOURCE0_ from s3.hector_request hectorrequ0_

java.lang.ClassCastException: HectorRequest

at NotifyMain1.main(NotifyMain1.java:37)
```

Can someone help what is missing and wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the data returned by the query "select hr from HectorRequest hr" is not "HectorRequest". It probably is a database data type (string, number, date, time, etc). So you have to build your "HectorRequest" object using the data returned by the query and not directly assign to it with a cast.